# Quel est le sens « les rencontres » ？

Tags: sens

[image]

Quel est le sens « les rencontres » et à la roulette？
Et pourriez-vous m'expliquer le tout paragraphe?

Merci d'avance.

Comment: Merci de donner l'auteur de l'extrait et le titre de l’œuvre quand tu fais une citation.  J'ai du mal à imaginer à ces mots un autre sens que leur sens propre, surtout dans le domaine des probabilités. [Rencontre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rencontre), [Roulette](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roulette) B1. Pour expliquer tout le paragraphe il faudrait probablement se référer à toute l’œuvre ou du moins au chapitre, il s'agit de la pensée de l'auteur. la question serait mieux sur https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ ou https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: C'est encore un extrait du livre de Introduction à la Philosophie de l'Histoire de Raymond Aron. Ici, Aron traite le thème de Déterminisme et Probabilité.

Comment: expériences et rencontre sont bien dans le dico, non? roulette= une combinaison donnée par la chance, aléatoire. Je constate qu' il utilise le pronom "on", donc, on est dans l'expérience et les rencontres que peuvent avoir les humains.

Comment: Le jeu de [roulette est un jeu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhahQtOgnFQ) de hasard de casino. Un disque porte 37 nombres, on lance une bille qui tombe dans une case pour désigner le sortant. Donc une série extraordinaire c'est sans doute 4 fois le même nombre, ou la suite 1 2 3 4.